# Insertion & Quick Sort on Array List of Objects

Tags: java, sorting

I could use some help with a Java Assignment, I've to write an insertion sort and quick sort to sort an arraylist of objects and have found myself stuck. The sort's don't seem to give the output I expect, ie. sorting the elements into alphabetical order.

--Insertion Sort--
Airbus A380,
Titanic,
Boxter,
Concorde,
Airbus A380

--Quick Sort--
Enzo,
Titanic,
Concorde,
Boxter,
Airbus A380

The above are the outputs I get.

```
protected ArrayList<Vehicle> insertionSort(ArrayList<Vehicle> list)
{

    ArrayList<Vehicle> sorted = new ArrayList<Vehicle>(list);

    int n = list.size();
    for (int j = 1; j < n; j++)
    {
        Vehicle key = list.get(j);
        Vehicle pivot = list.get(j-1);
        int i = j-1;

        for(i = j - 1; (i >= 0) && (pivot.compareTo(key)) > 0; i--)   // Smaller values are moving down
        {
            sorted.set(i, list.get(i));
        }
        sorted.set(i+1, key);    // Put the key in its proper location

    }

    return sorted;
}


protected ArrayList<Vehicle> quickSort(ArrayList<Vehicle> list, int low, int high)
{


    ArrayList<Vehicle> sorted = new ArrayList<Vehicle>(list);

    int i = low; int j = high;
    // Get the pivot element from the middle of the list
    Vehicle pivot = list.get(low + (high - low) / 2);

    // Divide into two lists
    while (i <= j) {
        // If the current value from the left list is smaller then the pivot
        // element then get the next element from the left list
        while (list.get(i).compareTo(pivot) > 0 )
        {
            i++;
        }
        // If the current value from the right list is larger then the pivot
        // element then get the next element from the right list
        while (list.get(j).compareTo(pivot) < 0 )  
        {
            j--;
        }

        // If we have found a value in the left list which is larger than
        // the pivot element and if we have found a value in the right list
        // which is smaller then the pivot element then we exchange the
        // values.
        // As we are done we can increase i and j
        if (i <= j) {
            sorted.set(i,list.get(j));
            sorted.set(j,list.get(i));
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }

    if (low < j)
        quickSort(sorted, low, j);
    if (i < high)
        quickSort(sorted, i, high);

    return sorted;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Homeworks should be done alone, agreed? You are missing the question in your text though.

Comment: The outputs from these sort algotithms are not what I expected (ie. alphabetical order. I can't seem to figure out where I went wrong and why . I do agree that homework assigments should be done alone, but there is no harm in asking for help, we are allowed to ask our tutors for help, there just wasn't enough time as many people needed help.

Comment: Set a breakpoint  at the start of your loops and step through to see what's happening..

Answer (score 0):

Try these fixes to the quick sort code:

```
        while (list.get(i).compareTo(pivot) < 0 )   // < (not >)
        // ...
        while (list.get(j).compareTo(pivot) > 0 )   // > (not <)
```